# How to make vscode to auto detect my customised language

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have create an langurage extension for vscode, however vscode language detection change to typescript sometimes. What's the way to make vscode to recognize my new own language.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the details how to detect your language in the package json file. Here's an example for ANTLR4 parsers/lexers:

```json
    "contributes": {
        "languages": [
            {
                "id": "antlr",
                "aliases": [
                    "ANTLR",
                    "antlr"
                ],
                "extensions": [
                    ".g",
                    ".g4"
                ],
                "firstLine": "^(lexer|parser)?\\s*grammar\\s*\\w+\\s*;",
                "configuration": "./antlr.configuration.json"
            }
        ],
```

You need something similar for your own language.